# gtk flash images in new thread

Tags: c, multithreading, user-interface, gtk

I use `g_thread_new()` to create a new thread to implement a flash image effect but only to show the later image but not to flash the 2 images.
And this is the code in the `GThreadFunc` function:

```
    gdk_threads_enter();
    draw_effect(background_map[mbullet.x][mbullet.y +1]);
    g_usleep(110000);
    draw_background(background_map[mbullet.x][mbullet.y +1]);
    gdk_threads_leave();
```

And this is `draw_**()`function:

```
   void draw_effect(GtkWidget *widget)
{
    gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(widget,fire_effect);
};
```

But the program can only show the image that `draw_background()`draws not `draw_effct()` does.
Unless I remove the `gdk_threads_enter()` and`gdk_threads_leave()` code,can the image flash as I wish.
What's wrong with my code?Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying a widget from a thread other than the main thread, which usually leads to all kinds of problems and unexpected behaviors in many GUI libraries, not only gtk.

I do understand the motivation to use a thread here though, since you need to wait a while before redrawing the background.

I recommend that you call `draw_effect` directly instead of creating a thread, and then use `g_timeout_add` to schedule a call to a function that will redraw the background.

It should be something like this (please modify as needed and do read the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add)):

Define this function:

```
gboolean
 redraw_background (gpointer user_data) {
    // ... get references to background_map and mbullet here ...

    draw_background(background_map[mbullet.x][mbullet.y +1]);

    return FALSE; // so it isn't called again
}
```

And elsewhere:

```
// Draw what you need to draw
draw_effect(background_map[mbullet.x][mbullet.y +1]);

// Schedule draw_background 110 ms from now
// user_data will be passed as a parameter to redraw_background
g_timeout_add (110,                 // milliseconds
           redraw_background,
           user_data);
```

Comment: And I just found that there is still much to learn in GUI programming and multi-thread,I still know little about it.

Comment: Glad to help :) GUI+threading can be tricky. Keep in mind that you should modify the GUI only on the main thread, `g_timeout_add` and `g_idle_add` will be useful here.